# How to write an Scala parser for arithmetic operations including string?

Tags: scala, parsing, arithmetic-expressions

I am trying to use [Scala Combinator-Parsing](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/combinator-parsing.html) to parse and arithmetic operation in which at least one of the variables is string. I am a beginner in scala and I like this feature of it!
For instance I wanna parse:
                (number + 2) * 4

It has a good example of parsing numbers (float and integer with parenthesis) like:

```
  class Arith extends JavaTokenParsers {  
      def expr: Parser[Any] = term~rep("+"~term | "-"~term)
      def term: Parser[Any] = factor~rep("*"~factor | "/"~factor)
      def factor: Parser[Any] = floatingPointNumber | "("~expr~")"
    }
```

and this one for string:

```
       object MyParsers extends RegexParsers {
        val ident: Parser[String] = """[a-zA-Z_]\w*""".r
       }
```

how can I change the first part to parse string beside numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should add it to the factor alternatives:

```
def factor: Parser[Any] = ident | floatingPointNumber | "("~expr~")"
```

Comment: then can I extend "class Arith extends JavaTokenParsers with RegexParsers" ??? because ident extends RegexParsers and Arith class that I mentioned above extends JavaTokenParsers, to add ident I should extend the class that ident is there, like MyParsers

Comment: `JavaTokenParsers` already extends `RegexParsers` so you do not need to combine the two. Also, `JavaTokenParsers` already defines `ident` so you do not really need `MyParsers` at all.